# Collimator for Dobsonian, same as Newtonian?

Tags: telescope, collimation

I have been looking on line for Collimator for my Meade Dobsonian. The only Collimators I can find are made for Newtonian Lenses. It's a 8" mirror with a 1.25" lens. Will this work for my telescope?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it will work. A Dobsonian is merely a Newtonian telescope on a special mount.